# What is the default `__reduce__` in Python?

Tags: python, pickle

```
import pickle

class A:
    pass

pickle.dumps(B().__reduce__())
```

yields

> `(<function _reconstructor at 0x1010143b0>, (<class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>, None))`

What is this function "_reconstructor".  It's neither `B`, `B.__init__`, nor `B.__new__` as I expected.

Comment: Poking at this in IPython, it tells me that it's actually `copy_reg._reconstructor`. It doesn't do much besides calling, in your case, `B.__new__()`, and calling `B.__init__()` if the class overrides it.

Comment: (Also, I'm guessing grepping the Python source for `_reconstructor(` would've told you this.)

Comment: millimoose: shouldn't your first comment be an answer, not a comment, which should be about the question? (Or like this comment, about a comment, also not as useful as a full-on answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to make 2 changes to get that result:

1. Change the name of your class from `A` to `B`.
2. Remove the outer `pickle.dumps()` call.

In any case, `pickle` is free to do anything it likes to reconstruct the object ;-)  In this case, you can find the `_reconstructor()` function in `Lib/copyreg.py`.

Comment: "In any case, pickle is free to do anything it likes" : surely you don't mean pickle is arbitrary and random?  It must follow a deterministic algorithm, for example: if the instance's class is a normal (not an extension) class, then ... else if the instance's class is an extension class, then if the class defines __reduce__, call it, else if a reduction function is registered (using the copy_reg module) then call the reduction function.  My description could be wrong:  why should a class have a default __reduce__ method, and why is it defined in the copy_reg module?

Comment: @bootchk, pickle can "do anything it likes" *consistent with* its documentation and purpose.  There's no guarantee that pickling the same object will produce the same pickle string across releases or pickle protocols, and even in a single release `pickle` and `cPickle` may produce different pickles for the same object.  The pickling of class instances is an involved topic, because classes in Python 2 come in 2 flavors ("classic' and "new style"), and several instance-pickling schemes have been defined in several pickle protocol versions.